# Build and install libsocketcan for x86_64

Tags: c++, installation, build, shared-objects, socketcan

I have downloaded the the [libsocketcan](https://github.com/lalten/libsocketcan) project and built and installed it successfully (no errors) using:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

and the configure step outputs:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

By my program still complains about the missing libsocketcan file:

```
qt.canbus.plugins.socketcan: Cannot load library socketcan: (socketcan: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
qt.canbus.plugins.socketcan: Cannot load library libsocketcan, some functionality will not be available.
Cannot load library socketcan: (socketcan: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

I notice that libsocketcan.* can be found in /usr/local/lib, but not in /usr/local/lib64.  I think thats the problem.  Why are the above steps not building and installing the 64-bit versions of the library?  I tried symlinking the .so file into the /usr/local/lib64 but it had no effect.  I also tried adding the path to the /usr/local/lib/libsocketcan.so in the ld.config.conf file but also no effect (and I ran ldconfig).

I'm working in Fedora 34 x86_64.

Comment: Notice the fedora 34 mentioned in the question.  There is no prebuilt RPM for libsocketcan on fedora.  I checked rpm finder and could not see a libsocketcan for Fedora (but if you know of one please post a link)

Comment: Yes, and I confirmed with "dnf provides */libsocketcan*".  I have can-utils-2021.08.0-1.fc34.x86_64 installed which only contains userspace utilities and tools